# Converting SQL query into Linq which used complex sum with group by

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my `Service` table's columns:

```
id
serverPlace
count
```

Here is a SQL query which I need to convert it into Linq:

```
 SELECT Service.id,
    Service.serverPlace,
    sum(Service.count * 12 + MONTH(getdate())) AS sum
   FROM Service
  GROUP BY Service.id, Service.serverPlace;
```

I do not know how to convert and implement `sum` section with Linq.

Comment: Is this like just normal Linq with in-memory Lists, or Entity Framework?

Comment: just like linq to objects

Comment: So the Linq is being translated to SQL in the background?

Comment: yes it will convert into sql in background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this :

```
var month = DateTime.Now.Month;
var result = await dbContext.Services.GroupBy(r=> new { r.Id, r.ServerPlace })
            .Select(r=> new {
             r.Key.Id,
             r.Key.ServerPlace,
             Sum = r.Sum(q=> q.Count*12 + month)
            }).ToArrayAsync();
```